# Manipulating a txt file

Tags: linux, bash, centos, scripting

I need to manipulate a lot of txt file in the same directory. Each file has the same format name (Pocket_???*????*?.pdb_OUTPUT.txt) and the same inner structure.

This is an example (file name: Pocket_001_1b47_A.pdb_OUTPUT.txt)

```
Input PDB-File:         /home/tommaso/Desktop/E3-ligase/CHAINS-approach/chains/1b47_A/1b47_biounit1_1b47_A.pdb
Pocket File:            /home/tommaso/Desktop/E3-ligase/CHAINS-approach/chains/1b47_A/Pocket_001_1b47_A.pdb
Pocket Surface:         649.1  
Hydrophobic Surface:    0.0     ( 0.0%)
Polar Surface:          441.0   (67.9%)
Acceptor Surface:       309.9   (47.7%)
Donnor Surface:         399.9   (61.6%)
Exposed To Solvent:     186.8   (28.8%)
Pocket Volume:          1255.9 
Hydrophobic Volume:     0.0     ( 0.0%)
Hydrophilic Volume:     229.1   (18.2%)
Flexible Volume:        134.2   (10.7%)
Rigid Volume:           120.2   ( 9.6%)
Buried Volume(B):       48.5    ( 3.9%)
Buried Volume(A):       0.0     ( 0.0%)
```

I need to obtain an output (Pocket_???*?????*?.pdb_OUTPUT_2.txt) in which are reported the name of the original file and the values present in each row, in the order in which they are reported in the original file, and separeted by comma.

es. output (Pocket_001_1b47_A.pdb_OUTPUT_2.txt):

```
Pocket_001_1b47_A.pdb_OUTPUT.txt,649.1,0.0,(0.0%),441.0,(67.9%),309.9,(47.7%),399.9,(61.6%),186.8,(28.8%),1255.9,0.0,( 0.0%),229.1,(18.2%),134.2,(10.7%),120.2,( 9.6%),120.2,( 9.6%),0.0,( 0.0%)
```

I think that it's necessary a loop to precessate each file and obtain for each of this the relative output file.

Could someone help me please? Thank you!!!

Comment: Loop over all files whose names correspond to pattern `Pocket_????????.pdb_OUTPUT.txt`. To generate the output file's **name**, use the shell's variable substitution to strip the `.txt`, then append `_2.txt` to the result. To generate the file's **content**, my first thought is an `awk` program that concatenates columns 2 and 3 starting with line 3. If input file columns are separated by tab characters, that's it. If they are separated by spaces, the spaces between parentheses are a little additional difficulty that needs to be handled.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had read about awk but I am no scripting expert and I would need a hand to create it because I am a beginner and I have to do an urgent job. And yes, the 2 and 3 column are separeted by space. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```bsh
for f in Pocket_??????????.pdb_OUTPUT.txt; do
    output=$(
        awk -F: 'NR>2{gsub("[[:blank:]]","",$2);print $2;}' "$f" \
        | sed 's/(/\n(/' \
        | paste -sd,
    )
    printf '%s,%s\n' "$f" "$output" >  "${f%.*}_2.txt"
done
```

**Explanation:**

- Loop the files using `for f in ...; do ... done`

Within the loop, chain ...

- `awk -F: 'NR>2{gsub("[[:blank:]]", "", $2); print $2;}'` to remove first 2 lines and remove all spaces and tabs from `$2`.
- `sed` to add new line with `(`
- `paste -sd,` to make a csv out of the previous

Then

- Put this together with the filename `"$f"` using `printf`
- Write to `"${f%.*}_2.txt"` (Remove `.txt` and add `_2.txt`)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without implementing any loop, by just passing the files with a wildcard to an `awk` command:

```
awk -F':' '{$1 =""; sub(/^[ \t]+/, "");
           sub(/[ \t]+$/, "");
           sub(/[ \t]+/,",");
           printf("%s%s",FNR==1?"":",",$1) >> substr(FILENAME, 0, length(FILENAME)-4)"_2.txt"}' Pocket_*.pdb_OUTPUT.txt
```

**Explanation**

- First the element before the colon is removed (`$1 =""`), as well as the blank spaces before (`sub(/^[ \t]+/, "")`) and after (`sub(/[ \t]+$/, "")`) the remaining items.
- The spaces between elements are substituted by a comma (`sub(/[ \t]+/,",")`)
- Finally, we output the elements to the correct file, using the input `FILENAME` modified, adding a comma between elements if they are not the first line of a specific file.